# is there a clean way to timeout multiple curl at once in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl_multi_init() to fetch resources on multiple urls, but have the following issue:

My curls properly timeout when they cannot connect to their url (thanks to CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT)

they could also timeout when the request is taking too long (CURLOPT_TIMEOUT)

but I can't find a way to tell curl_multi to timeout when the whole process is taking too long

```
   do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        curl_multi_select($mh, 1);
    } while ($active > 0);
```

curl_multi_select has a timeout parameter, but it doesn't seem to help here.

My question is : do I have to handle it myself with some code, or did I miss something in curl documentation ?

Here is the beginning of my function and initCurl

```
protected function getContents(array $urls, callable $formatter, array $headers = [], $maxRetry = 3)
{
    $curls = [];
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $curl = $this->initCurl($url, $headers);

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl);
        $curls[$url] = $curl;
    }

    $active = null;
    do { // this loop is taking too long, resulting in a 504 error from nginx
        curl_multi_select($mh, 1);
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($active > 0);

    ... (rest of the function)
}


protected function initCurl($url, array $headers = [])
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl,
        [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => false,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 2,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 2
        ]
    );

    return $curl;
}
```

The more $urls I have to reach, the more the whole process takes time :

(url timeout 2s * 3 retries) * number of urls

I would say there is also a problem with asynchronicity as it takes longer the more I have $urls to reach...